# How to use Windows LLKeyboard Hook for Combination Keypresses in C++

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, setwindowshookex

I have a working Windows hook to detect the simple keypress combinations of both LCTRL + x, and LCTRL + v. The only problem I have is when I press LCTRL, then release, then press x or v, my program thinks they are still being pressed together.
Here is my Hook Callback function:

```
HHOOK hookHandle;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookdata;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int code, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    if (code >= 0)
    {
        if (wparam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            hookdata = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lparam);
            switch(hookdata.vkCode)
            {
                case(88):
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL))
                    {
                        std::cout<<"CTRL X PRESSED";
                    }
                    break;
                case (86):
                    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL))
                    {
                       std::cout<<"CTRL V PRESSED";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, code, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Example Input

```
Test 1) Press LCTRL, Press X
Test 2) Press LCTRL, Release LCTRL, Press X
```

Expected Output

```
Test 1) CTRL X PRESSED
Test 2) No Output
```

Actual Output

```
Test 1) CTRL X PRESSED (WORKING)
Test 2) CTRL X PRESSED (NOT WORKING)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incorrectly checking `GetAsyncKeyState`'s return value:

> If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. **If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.** However, you should not rely on this last behavior; for more information, see the Remarks.

Change the check to `GetAsyncKeyState(...) & 0x8000` to fix that by checking only the highest bit.

A small thing: Microsoft made the VK values the same as the ASCII code. Since complete portability is of small concern here, you can use `'X'` and `'V'` instead of `88` and `86` to better express intent.